# Wpf Animation SetWindowPos

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

So i have an WPF application, in some cases when an event occur i use native SetWindowPos on the handle of the WPF window to bring it in front or send to background.
Usually when SetWindowPos called there is also visual content change in the window.
What happens in some cases is that visual content does not change until mouse is moved over the window or there is an input event (mouse click or similar).
So the question is can this be in some way related with the SetWindowPos function?

Full calling example

```
    User32.SetWindowPos(SHELL_HWND, HWND.HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP.SWP_NOSIZE | SWP.SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP.SWP_NOMOVE);
    User32.SetWindowPos(SHELL_HWND, HWND.HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP.SWP_TOPMPOST);
```

Comment: What 's the `SWP_TOPMPOST`? There does not seem to be this flag on the [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos).

Comment: Indeed i removed it but that was not the case, i think the problem is one of custom controls i am using. In conjunction with SetWindowPos which resizes the main window it causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was coming from a custom control blocking the UI thread.